# Intelligent fitting with python

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

Is there a more intelligent function than `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` in Python?
I also need to define a function to fit data with.

I've spend ages trying to fit data with it. I can fit only basic functions and fitting two lines with piecewise function is impossible while the y-axis has low values like 0.01-0.05 and x-axis values like 20-60.
I know I have to plug in initial values, but still it takes too much time and sometimes it does not work.

**EDIT**

I added graph where are data I fitted and you can see the effect of changing bounds in `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`.

The function I fit with is this one:

```
def abslines(x,a,b,c,d):
    return np.piecewise(x, [x < -b/a, x >= -b/a], [lambda x: a*x+b+d, lambda x: c*(x+b/a)+d])
```

Initial conditions are same everytime and I think they are close enough:

```
p0=[-0.001,0.2,0.005,0.]
```

because the values of parameters from best fit are:

```
[-0.00411946  0.19895546  0.00817832  0.00758401]
```

Bounds are:

No bounds;

```
bounds=([-1.,0.,0.,0.],[0.,1.,1.,1.])
bounds=([-0.5,0.01,0.0001,0.],[-0.001,0.5,0.5,1.])
bounds=([-0.1,0.01,0.0001,0.],[-0.001,0.5,0.1,1.])
bounds=([-0.01,0.1,0.0001,0.],[-0.001,0.5,0.1,1.])
```

starting with no bounds, end with best bounds

[image: Fitting data and changing bound in scipy.optimize.curve_fit]

Still I think, that this takes too much time and `curve_fit` can find it better. This way I have to almost specify the function and it seems like I am fitting by changing parameters not that `curve_fit` is fitting.

Comment: perhaps `numpy.polyfit` or `numpy.linalg.lstsq`

Comment: Hmmm, I forgot to add that I fit with various functions, so I need to define function to fit data with. Polyfit is useless for my case. I will edit question. But thanks :)

Comment: Sorry but what exactly do you mean? What do you mean that you "need to define function to fit data with"?

Comment: Well polyfit works the way that I specify the number of polynomials to fit data with. But that is not what I need. I want to fit data with two, three, four... linear functions piecewise. Or to fit it with exponentials or square roots or combinations. 

I would like to fit it with something like scipy.optimize.curve_fit. I like that you can say "fit it with ..." and specify the function. But it does not work for low values and takes much time to specify correct initial conditions.

Comment: Could you post an example where curve_fit fails to do what you want? Curve_fit can fit any function you supply. Convergence depends on a lot of parameters including your initial guess. From your description I would guess that there is nothing wrong with curve_fit but you are not using it correctly.

Comment: Any curve fitting function is going to have some limitations, some of which you can overcome by having a very thorough understanding of how the functions works. I would recommend reading all the documentation on `curve_fit` and trying again.

Other than that, if you have specific needs of how you'd like it to work, then if you understand how curve fitting in general works, you can create your own fits for any functional form you desire using `numpy.linalg.lstsq`. The documentation has a very simple example for fitting linear data.

Comment: Ok, I will try to add study of effect of specifying bounds now.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what is exactly the regression algorithm in Python it is quite impossible to give a definitive answer. Probably the calculus is iterative and requires initial guesses, which are probably derived from the specified bounds. So, the bounds have an indirect effect on the convergence and the results.

I suggest to try a simpler algorithm (not iterative, no initial guess) coming from this paper : https://fr.scribd.com/document/380941024/Regression-par-morceaux-Piecewise-Regression-pdf

The code is easy to write in any computer language. I suppose this can be done with Python as well.

The piecewise function to be fitted is :  [image]
The parameters to be computed are a1, p1, q1, p2 and q2.

[image]

The result is shown on the next figure, with the approximate values of the parameters.

[image]

So that, no bounds are required to be specified and as a consequence no problems related to bounds.

NOTE : The method is based on the fitting of a convenient integral equation such as shown in the above referenced paper. The numerical calculus of the integral is subjected to deviations if the number of points is too small. In the present case, they are a large number of points. So, even scattered this is a favourable case for the practical application of this method.

Answer (score 0):

1.Algorithms behind curve_fit expect differentiable functions, thus it can go south if given a non-differential one.

2. For a more powerful interface to curve fitting, have a look at `lmfit`.